# Navigation: Robot cannnot reach goal

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm using navigation stack on a turtlebot-based robot. When launching move_base.launch, I can send 2d nav goal in Rviz and robot cannot find its way to the goal, it just makes small movements. It only reaches it when it is a orientation change but not position one.
I looked for errors with roswtf and I get:

**ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't: * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/global_costmap/footprint) * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/local_costmap/footprint)**

How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386543/navigation:-robot-cannnot-reach-goal/) by [alejandrolri](https://answers.ros.org/users/84337/alejandrolri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-09-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-15**:
Typing `turtlebot footprint` into the search bar at the top of this page gets 259 hits. Please review some of those existing answers. If you figure it out, and it's different from what @osilva said, you can help out by answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your help. There wasn't any problem with topics.
Tuning navigation parameters solved my issue.

---

Originally posted by [alejandrolri](https://answers.ros.org/users/84337/alejandrolri/) with karma: 16 on 2021-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-20**:
Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you look at this thread: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/266

Looks it may be caused by either your odometer not reset or sending multiple `/cmd_vel` messages. So one way to dig deeper is to take a look at `rostopic list`

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1